# JavaScript in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm quiet new to building webpages and just started building one with Bootstrap 5.
I want to add/remove the bootstrap class "bg-opacity" to my navbar based on viewport width and thought I can do so with JS. But the function I found is not working, cause BS doesn't use JQuery anymore. Is there an easy way to add/remove classes that exist in Bootstrap 5?

I would be very happy about an answer.

Cheers and thanks in advance :)

I tried to use this function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var alterClass = function() {
      var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
      if (ww < 767) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('bg-opacity-75');
      } else if (ww >= 768) {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('bg-opacity-75');
      };
    };
    $(window).resize(function(){
      alterClass();
    });
    //Fire it when the page first loads:
    alterClass();
  });
```

Comment: Don't all jquery start with a `$`?

Comment: @Richie `jQuery` is an alias of `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write Media Queries in JS with [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) and toggle the class based on if the query matches or not.

Here we check for the `min-width: 768px`. If your screen size is below 768 pixels, `mediaQuery.matches` will be `false`. If your screen is 768 pixels or above, then `mediaQuery.matches` will be `true`.

Based on that boolean it will add or remove the class with [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method.

```
const navBar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
const mediaQuery = matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');

function alterClass(match) {
  navBar.classList.toggle('bg-opacity-75', !match);
}

alterClass(mediaQuery.matches);

mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  alterClass(event.matches);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. I tried your code, but somehow it doesn't work. 

I added a console.log() after the two constants to see, what the mediaQuery is returning

It always returns "matches: false" no matter, what window size i use. I guess it shouldn't be like that based on your answer? Any suggestions what could be the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked again and noticed that I didn't create a valid media query. The brackets around the query were missing. Now it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. JavaScript is still very new to me, i guess when i get a little more into it, i could have found that small syntax error myself, but right now, I'm still depending very much on other peoples functions.